# rotation angle of the perspective matrix

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision

How can I detect the rotation angle from a perspective matrix?

I wrote this code ,but the resulted angle doesn't exceed 40 ...

```
Mat mmat;
mmat.create(3,3,CV_32FC1);
mmat=getPerspectiveTransform(templPoints,imgPoints);
cout<< mmat<<endl<<endl;
float angle=acos(mmat.at<double>(0,0));
angle=(angle*180)/3.14;
cout<<"angle is"<<angle<<endl;
```

Comment: What rotation, it's a perspective matrix?

Comment: Perspective matrix is the projection. It doesn't incorporate rotations, they are stored in modelview matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

getPerspectiveTransform returns an homography matrix which can be decomposed like this:

[R11,R12,T1]

[R21,R22,T2]

[ P , P , 1]

R represents a rotation matrix, T represents a translation, and P represents a perspective warp.

More info on what rotation matrix represents:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/RotationMatrix.html

Answer (score 2):

The process is as follows. Consider a 3D point X, represented in homogeneous coordinates by a column vector [ x1, x2, x3, 1]' (where I use the prime symbol "'" to indicate transposition). Consider then a 2D point u = [u1, u2, 1]' that is the image of X in the (perspective) camera. Then the camera's projection is represented by a 3x4 projection matrix P such that

u = P * X .

where "*" means row-by-column product: u1 = P11*x1 + P12*x2 + P13*x3 + P14, etc.

Matrix P can be decomposed in the product of two matrices:

P = K * Q

where K is a 3x3 upper-diagonal matrix

```
K = [ fx s  cx
      0  fy cy
      0  0  1 ]
```

that represents the camera, and Q is a 3x4 matrix

```
Q = [R | t]
```

where R is the 3x3 rotation matrix of the camera, and t is the 3x1 translation vector.

If you are given the project matrix P, the procedure for recovering the K, R and t is as follows:

1. Compute the "[RQ decomposition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_decomposition)" of P
2. Extract R from Q (just read its leftmost 3 columns)