# How to get the rotation angle from findHomography?

Tags: python, opencv, math, geometry, homography

I want to rotate the image without resorting to `cv2.warpPerspective()`. How to get angle from `cv2.findHomography()` function output?

[It didn't help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10969170/rotation-angle-of-the-perspective-matrix)

```py
# Find homography
H, mask = cv2.findHomography(points1, points2, cv2.RANSAC)

# for example my H:
array([[ 1.20001976e-01,  5.19205433e-04, -1.21739638e+01],
       [ 1.51272694e-03,  1.18686196e-01, -1.59772594e+01],
       [ 1.98308723e-06, -1.18197608e-07,  1.00000000e+00]])

# What should be the someFunction function?
angle = someFunction(H) # from 0 to 360

rotated = imutils.rotate(image, angle=angle)
```

Comment: openCV already has a [`decomposeHomographyMat`](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/calib3d/doc/camera_calibration_and_3d_reconstruction.html#decomposehomographymat) method to do this

Comment: @EdChum then how to get "K – The input intrinsic camera calibration matrix." from the available data?

Comment: Perhaps use getAffine https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/da/d54/group__imgproc__transform.html#ga8f6d378f9f8eebb5cb55cd3ae295a999 and then use getRTfromHomogeneous https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/dd/d76/classcv_1_1detail_1_1AffineWarper.html#ac54ef5b572ef0727c0b8e324d584b393

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the transformation between the two set of points is a scale + rotation + translation, then the homography will simply be an affine matrix in which the 2x2 upper-left block is a scaled rotation. In this case, compute the angle using:

```
angle = math.atan2(H[1,0], H[0,0])
```

If some other kind of transformation can creep in (shearing, projective), it is safer to first perform an SVD decomposition of the 2x2 upper-left block to recover a rotation:

```
u, _, vh = numpy.linalg.svd(H[0:2, 0:2])
R = u @ vh
angle = math.atan2(R[1,0], R[0,0])
```